# How to solve black & white knights problem in 3×3 grid

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, a-star

Here is a test of Artificial Intelligence informed and uninformed search algorithms.

> We have a 3×3 grid where B means BLACK KNIGHT and W is WHITE KNIGHT of chess.
>
> ```
> +---+---+---+            +---+---+---+
> | W |   | W |            | B |   | B |
> +---+---+---+            +---+---+---+
> |   |   |   |    ---->   |   |   |   |  
> +---+---+---+            +---+---+---+
> | B |   | B |            | W |   | W |
> +---+---+---+            +---+---+---+
> ```
>
> B and W can "L" move exactly like knights chess pieces.
>
> What is the best search algorithm to put black ones into current white ones squares and white ones into current black ones square?
>
> 1. A STAR
> 2. BFS
> 3. DFS
> 4. HILL CLIMBING

I'm really confused and I don't know the correct choice.

Comment: Backtrack algorithm.

Comment: Note that whatever the algorithm you select, you have to pay attention not to go through the same node several times , i.e. through the same position. Traditionnaly, chess programmes use hash tables when analysing positions with a low number of pieces

Comment: In my understanding, *Hill climbing* method provides a local minimum, not an absolute one. It should not answer the question here.

Comment: Damien tnx, it's a test and among the A* and BFS what do you prefer?

Comment: It is difficult to answer. As the number of positions is rather small (756), you are sure that a simple DFS will not use too much memory and will be rather fast, under the condition to remove duplicate positions. The A* algorithms could be faster, maybe (or maybe not) slightly more difficult to implement ... In an ideal World, you will implement both and compare :)

Comment: Correction: only 420 possible positions, as the central square cannot be joined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important aspect is that the number of possible positions is rather small :

```
420 = Binomial(8,2) * Binomial(6, 2)
```

A consequence is that whatever which the algorithm is selected, you have to pay attention not to go through the same node several times , i.e. through the same position. Traditionally, chess programmes use hash tables when analyzing positions with a low number of pieces. Here, taking into account the small number of possible positions, it is possible to select a *perfect* hashing, i.e. with no collusion.

Concerning the algorithms:

- *Hill climbing* method provides a local minimum, not an absolute one. It should not answer the question here
- DFS (e.g. implemented with backtracking) does not seem the best here, as you take the risk to go deeply in a false route
- A* algorithm are often very efficient. However, it relies of a good heuristic estimation of a given node. Here, after having looking for a solution *by hand*, it is clear that the Knights have to turn around a long time in a short surface (*crazy horses*). Difficult to find a good heuristic in this situation
- BFS generally has the drawback that it can generate a very large amount of memory and consequently a large time spent visiting these nodes. Here, it won't be the case, due to the limited number of possible nodes (positions) and due to the hashing. Moreover, with BFS, as soon as we get a solution, we are certain it is the shortest one

I have therefore implemented the BFS in C++. The result is provided about instantaneously.

The 16 half-moves are given hereafter:

```
+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  
| W |   | W |  |   |   | W |  |   |   | W |  |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  
|   |   |   |  |   |   |   |  |   |   | B |  | W |   | B |
+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  
| B |   | B |  | B | W | B |  |   | W | B |  |   | W | B |
+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  

+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  
| B |   |   |  | B |   | W |  | B | B | W |  | B | B | W |
+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  
| W |   |   |  | W |   |   |  | W |   |   |  |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  
|   | W | B |  |   |   | B |  |   |   |   |  |   |   | W |
+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  

+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  
| B |   | W |  | B | W | W |  | B | W | W |  | B | W |   |
+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  
|   |   |   |  |   |   |   |  |   |   | B |  | W |   | B |
+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  
| B |   | W |  | B |   |   |  |   |   |   |  |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  

+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  
|   | W |   |  |   | W |   |  |   | W | B |  |   |   | B |  | B |   | B |
+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  
| W |   | B |  |   |   | B |  |   |   | B |  |   |   | B |  |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  
|   | B |   |  |   | B | W |  |   |   | W |  | W |   | W |  | W |   | W |
+---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+  +---+---+---+
```

And the programme:

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <array>
#include    <vector>
#include    <tuple>
#include    <algorithm>

int depl[9][2] = {
    {5,7}, {6,8}, {3,7}, {2,8}, {-1,-1},
    {0,6}, {1,5}, {0,2}, {1,3}};

struct position {
    std::array<int, 2> B;
    std::array<int, 2> W;
    int hash;
    position *up = nullptr;
    position (int w0, int w1, int b0, int b1) {
        if (w0 > w1) std::swap (w0, w1);
        if (b0 > b1) std::swap (b0, b1);
        B[0] = b0;
        B[1] = b1;
        W[0] = w0;
        W[1] = w1;
        cal_hash();
    }
    position() {};
    void cal_hash () {
        hash = 1000*B[0] + 100*B[1] + 10*W[0] + W[1];
    }
    std::vector<position> gene_mov (int white_black) {
        std::vector<position> res;
        if (!white_black) {     // White
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                    int pos = depl[W[i]][j];
                    bool test = (pos == W[1-i]) || (pos == B[0]) || (pos == B[1]);
                    if (!test) {
                        res.push_back (position(pos, W[1-i], B[0], B[1]));
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {                // Black
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                    int pos = depl[B[i]][j];
                    bool test = (pos == B[1-i]) || (pos == W[0]) || (pos == W[1]);
                    if (!test) {
                        res.push_back (position(W[0], W[1], pos, B[1-i]));
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
        return res;
    }
    void print (int shift = 0) {
        char displ[3][3] = {{' ',' ',' '},
                            {' ',' ',' '},
                            {' ',' ',' '}};
        displ[1][1] = ' ';
        displ[2 - W[0]/3][W[0]%3] = 'W';
        displ[2 - W[1]/3][W[1]%3] = 'W';
        displ[2 - B[0]/3][B[0]%3] = 'B';
        displ[2 - B[1]/3][B[1]%3] = 'B';
        Wshift(shift);
        std::cout << "+---+---+---+\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            Wshift(shift);
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                std::cout << "| " << displ[i][j] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << "|\n";
            Wshift(shift);
            std::cout << "+---+---+---+\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    void Wshift (int shift) {
        for (int i = 0; i < shift; ++i)
            std::cout << " ";
    }
};

std::tuple<bool, int, std::vector<position>> find_moves (position &first, position &end) {
    std::vector<position> moves;
    std::array<bool, 10000> pos_found = {false};
    std::vector<std::vector<position>> dfs;
    using pvector = std::vector<position>;
    dfs.push_back(pvector(1, first));

    int iter = 1;
    int white_black = 0;
    while (true) {
        int n = dfs[iter-1].size();
        if (n == 0) return std::make_tuple(false, 0, moves);
        dfs.push_back(pvector(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            auto candidates = dfs[iter-1][i].gene_mov(white_black);
            for (auto &c: candidates) {
                if (pos_found[c.hash]) continue;
                c.up = &dfs[iter-1][i];
                if (c.hash == end.hash) {   // Last position attained: get the previous moves
                        moves.resize(iter+1);
                        moves[iter] = c;
                        for (int i = iter - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            moves[i] = *(moves[i+1].up);
                        }
                        return std::make_tuple(true, iter, moves);
                }
                pos_found[c.hash] = true;
                dfs[iter].push_back (c);
            }
        }
        iter++;
        white_black = 1 - white_black;
    }

    return std::make_tuple(false, -1, moves);
}

int main () {
    position first(6, 8, 0, 2);
    position end(0, 2, 6, 8);

    bool success;
    int n_iter;
    std::vector<position> moves;
    std::tie (success, n_iter, moves) = find_moves (first, end);
    std::cout << "success = " << success << "\n";
    std::cout << "n_iter = " << n_iter << "\n";

    for (auto &m: moves) {
        m.print();
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Damien, Tnx, Your answer was awesome

Comment: Note that I made a small correction in the code. By insuring `w0 < w1` and `b0 < b1`, I improve the efficiency of the hashing. The result is not impacted, maybe the efficiency a little bit

Comment: Damien, would you please explain "crazy horses" in A* more? I didn't understand this part

Comment: Look at the solution. The horses seem turning in an erratic way in a small area. In this condition, it seems difficult to find a good heuristic that would be able to guess what are the a priori most interesting routes to follow. A* algorithms are based on the use of such a heuristic. Another issue with A*: when a solution is found, we cannot be sure it is the shortest one.

Answer (score 2):

A* should be the appropriate algorithm for this problem. As a target-heuristic, u could use the no. of moves required to reach the target destination assuming the board is empty, which is always <= the actual amount of moves required.

Comment: At the beginning, I was also confident in the use of A*. Then, after having tried to solve it *by hand*, I discovered that the horses become crazy, and that it is rather difficult to find a good heuristic in this condition. You can have a look at the Chess solution in my post.